# How can I pass a value to a android dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog in which I am trying to pass a float to, like this:

```
public void rateDialog(View v){
        // custom dialog

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
    // Set other dialog properties

        // Create the AlertDialog
        builder.setTitle("Rate this Beer");
        builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rate_stars, null));
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) this.findViewById(R.id.beerRatingBar);
        float stars = ratingBar.getRating();


        dialog.show(stars);

    // Create the AlertDialog



    }
```

Is this actually possible and if so how?

Comment: What about using a DialogFragment? Are you targeting less than API 11?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as final:

```
public void rateDialog(View v){
    // custom dialog

   final Float value = 1;

}
```

and use it in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your rate_stars.xml, how it looks.

If you are using RatingBar, then you can set rating in java file, and then call show method.

If you are not using RatingBar, try it it will be simple in setting ratings.