# Passing value to dialog that's running from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my project I have an activity A and a dialog A1 inside A. From A1 I can call to activity B. In activity B have some string value I want to get and set it on Edittext in dialog A1 that had value already when finish activity B.

How can I do that?

Comment: The power of google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041558/how-can-i-pass-a-value-to-a-android-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a `DialogFragment`. Add it to the screen with a `FragmentTransaction` when the dialog needs to be shown. Either keep a reference to it while it is showing, or give it a tag when you add it so that you can find it later by its tag.
2. Use `StartActivityForResult` to start the next `Activity`.
3. Use `onActivityResult` to get the result of the second `Activity`. If the dialog is showing, use some public method you define to manipulate it. If it's not showing, you could just show it again with the new information.